# How to escape border collapse in a table with border-collapse: collapse?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am making a table where I want the first and last column to be sticky. This part I have already taken care of (I made the container resizable that way you can get the scrollbar to see it.)

My problem is that I want the sticky columns to have a border-right and border-left respectively. When the table is not scrolled yet, you can see that the borders are working exactly how I want it to look. However, you when start scrolling the border disappear for an unexplainable reason. When I turn `border-collapse: collapse` off for the table this bug goes away, however, I need `border-collapse: collapse` for the rest of the table design to be correct. Therefore, I wonder, is there a way I can make specific borders inside a table escape the tables border collapsing behaviour which seems to be messing it up? Please help me fix this issue.

I have tried replacing the border with a box shadow, however, the exact same issue is happening still.

I have also tried using ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, however, if you comment that solution back in from my snippet, you will see that it is not working and I can't get the borders to line up correctly.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.wl-table-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wl-table {
  --wlt-background: white;
  --wlt-column-gap: 3rem;
  --wlt-border-width: 0.0625rem;
  --wlt-border-style: solid;
  --wlt-border-color: #ccc;
  --wlt-border: var(--wlt-border-width) var(--wlt-border-style) var(--wlt-border-color);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.wl-table th,
.wl-table td {
  padding-block: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: var(--wlt-border);
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}

.wl-table th+th,
.wl-table td+td {
  padding-left: var(--wlt-column-gap);
}

.wl-table th[data-type="stretch"],
.wl-table td[data-type="stretch"] {
  width: 100%;
}

.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-start"],
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-start"] {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: var(--wlt-background);
  padding-right: 1rem;
  border-right: var(--wlt-border);
}


/*.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-start"]::after,
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-start"]::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: calc(0 - var(--wlt-border-width) + 1rem);
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--wlt-border-width); 
    background: var(--wlt-border-color);
    z-index: 1;
}*/

.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-end"],
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-end"] {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: var(--wlt-background);
  padding-left: 1rem;
  border-left: var(--wlt-border);
}


/*.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-end"]::after,
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-end"]::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(0 - var(--wlt-border-width) - 1rem);
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--wlt-border-width); 
    background: var(--wlt-border-color);
    z-index: 1;
}*/
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="wl-table-container">
    <table class="wl-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Order</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
          <th scope="col" data-type="stretch">Customer</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr tabindex="0">
          <td data-type="sticky-start">#100000000023</td>
          <td>$199.99</td>
          <td>12:38 - 21. Jan. 2024</td>
          <td data-type="stretch">Peter Pan</td>
          <td data-type="sticky-end"><button>:</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr tabindex="0">
          <td data-type="sticky-start">#100000000024</td>
          <td>$199.99</td>
          <td>12:38 - 21. Jan. 2024</td>
          <td data-type="stretch">Peter Griffin</td>
          <td data-type="sticky-end"><button>:</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr tabindex="0">
          <td data-type="sticky-start">#100000000025</td>
          <td>$199.99</td>
          <td>12:38 - 21. Jan. 2024</td>
          <td data-type="stretch">Peter Bealish</td>
          <td data-type="sticky-end"><button>:</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr tabindex="0">
          <td data-type="sticky-start">#100000000026</td>
          <td>$199.99</td>
          <td>12:38 - 21. Jan. 2024</td>
          <td data-type="stretch">Peter Parker</td>
          <td data-type="sticky-end"><button>:</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-start"],
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-start"] {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: var(--wlt-background);
    padding-right: 1rem;
}

.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-start"]::before,
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-start"]::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -1px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--wlt-border-width); 
    background: var(--wlt-border-color);
    z-index: 1;
}

.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-end"],
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-end"] {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: var(--wlt-background);
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-end"]::after,
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-end"]::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -1px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--wlt-border-width); 
    background: var(--wlt-border-color);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Wow, so it appears the reason why my ::after solution did not work was because I used calc(0 - ...) whereas I needed to use calc(0rem - ...) For some reason calc requires that you specify a unit when using 0 so with this fix it is now working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the border-collapse: collapse property, which merges adjacent borders into a single border. To solve this issue, use the **outline** property instead of **border**. The outline property is not affected by **border-collapse**.

```
.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-start"],
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-start"] {
    /* ... Your other styles ... */
    outline: var(--wlt-border);
}

.wl-table th[data-type="sticky-end"],
.wl-table td[data-type="sticky-end"] {
    /* ... Your other styles ... */
    outline: var(--wlt-border);
}
```

Comment: outline cannot be used on only one side unfortunately, so that wouldn't work.